# Why is my code pushing every permutation twice?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm confused as to why my code is pushing every permutation twice. Please someone help. I'm using heap's algorithm:

```
var regex = /(.)\1+/g;

function permAlone(str) {
  var newArray = str.split('');
  var n = newArray.length;
  var permutations = [];
  var tmp;

  function swap(index1, index2) {
    tmp = newArray[index1];
    newArray[index1] = newArray[index2];
    newArray[index2] = tmp;
  }

  function generate(n, newArray) {
    if (n === 1) {
      permutations.push(newArray.join(''));
    } else {
      for(var i = 0; i<n-1; i++) {
        generate(n-1, newArray);
        swap(n % 2 ? 0 : i, n-1);
        permutations.push(newArray.join(''));
      }

      generate(n-1, newArray);
    }      
  }  

  generate(n, newArray);
  return permutations;
}    

permAlone('aab');
```

The array that is returned is:

```
["aab", "aab", "aab", "baa", "baa", "aba", "aba", "aba", "baa", "baa"]
```

So as you can see, the permutations are appearing many more times than intended for each thing. Any help would be great

Comment: In addition to duplicates, the second call to `generate(n-1, newArray);` is unnecessary. It's just going to do the same thing as the last last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Just one question: since the string is `aab`, do you expect two `aab` and two `aba` ... (because there is two `a`) or just one?

Comment: ...and why the regex..?

Answer (score 1):

The code's a little complex and it's difficult to track given the recursion, but if all you want is an array with only unique values, you can simply apply the following code to the result array:

```
 function stripDuplicates(input) {
     if (!input || typeof(input) !== 'object' || !('length' in input)) {
         throw new Error('input argument is not array.');
     }

     var newArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         if (newArray.indexOf(input[i]) === -1) {
             newArray.push(input[i]);
         }
     }

     return newArray;
 }
```

This could also be done functionally rather than imperatively, but that's really more of a preference than an optimization issue.

Bálint also points out that you could merely convert the result to a `Set`, then convert the `Set` back to an `Array`, which would automatically strip out any duplicates. Beware, though, that `Set` is a comparatively new affordance in Javascript and will not function in pre-ES6 environments.

Comment: Or just put them in a set and convert it to an array. Seems like no one likes sets.

Comment: @Bálint Or that too! Feel free to add that as your own answer -- it's a great idea. The advantage of this is that you can do anything else within the loop as well, if they later have any other requirements. I chose not to do that because I try to make my SO answers as backwards-compatible as possible and the Set object only exists in ES6+.

Comment: Nah, you should just add it. I don't have the time right now.

Comment: "The advantage of this is that you can do anything else within the loop as well." The disadvantage is that this is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to:

```
permutations.push(newArray.join(''));
```

inside of your for loop. That shouldn't be there. And then, of course if you are permuting strings that have duplicate characters, well, expect to see dupes. e.g., if you permute the string "aa" you'll get two entries from this algorithm "aa" and "aa". Heap's algorithm doesn't try to remove dupes, it treats each element as unique within the string. Obviously, it's trivial to use remove dupes if that's something you care about doing.